# validation error の先頭に 必ず Content と追加されてしまう

Tags: ruby-on-rails

### 画像

[image: エラーを発生させています]

### 現状

画像をアップロードした時に CSV PDF 以外のファイルをアップロードしたときに エラーメッセージを出したい

### やったこと

yml の 先頭にそもそも content と 入ってしまっているのではないか? <= 表示したいメッセージのみでした

エラーメッセージのerrors を pryにてチェック この時点で contentが入ってしまっている

[image: pry]

view に 直接書いている? <= 書いていないと思います

### お願いします

これらの点からみて よき 解決案があれば 教えて頂けると助かります

Answer (score 1):

すごく 情けないのですが
単純にactive record を記載していなかっただけでした...

恥ずかしい限りです